# How to use "issuer" tag in ALFA plugin?

Tags: delegation, xacml, xacml3, xacml2, alfa

I am writing some administrative policies on ALFA plugin but I find out there's no such function of it. Does anyone know this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to generate the `issuer` element separately using an `ant` script and some logic to generate the value of the issuer field e.g. by adding the dn of a certificate.

It all depends on how your XACML engine implements delegation.

ALFA itself doesn't do anything to the issuer field.

Cheers,
David.