# How to define a administrative policy in ALFA for delegation?

Tags: access-control, delegation, xacml, xacml3, alfa

How can I write ALFA policies which allow delegation of certain actions on certain resources? In XACML these are called Administrative policies.

(As described in http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-administration-v1-spec-en.html)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cannot.

Because the ALFA language does not let you set a `PolicyIssuer`, you cannot write delegation policies.

You could write standard policies in ALFA and then write a script that would insert the `PolicyIssuer` element.

This is similar to the question asked here: [How to use "issuer" tag in ALFA plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25128025/how-to-use-issuer-tag-in-alfa-plugin)

Comment: Is there any updates on Delegation of Authority rules writing using ALFA if so can you provide a sample @David